# ¿Cómo compilar c++ con visual studio code?

Tags: c++, vscode

Estoy intentando **compilar** un archivo llamado `main.cpp` con [**Visual Studio Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/), siguiendo [**estas instrucciones**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) desde la documentación oficial del mismo editor (en inglés), esta es mi estructura de proyecto:

```
c++ 
.vscode
    c_cpp_properties.json
    launch.json
    tasks.json
main.cpp
```

Este es mi archivo `c_cpp_properties.json`, (trabajo bajo Ubuntu)

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "/usr/include/c++/5",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include/c++/5",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "/usr/include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Este es mi archivo `launch.json` (Archivo necesario para poder compilarlo desde el editor)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "preLaunchTask": "g++",
            "name": "Compile and debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Este es mi archivo `tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-g", "main.cpp"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Y por último el simple archivo `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Cuando presiono <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>Shift</kbd> **+** <kbd>B</kbd> (combinación de letras compilar y depurar el archivo anterior), me crea un archivo llamado `a.out` y salta una pequeña consola con cuatro pestañas las cuales respectivamente muestran lo siguiente:

1. **PROBLEMS**

   > No problems have been detected in the workspace so far.
2. **OUTPUT**

   > Aquí nunca se muestra nada **a menos que el código tenga un error**
3. **DEBUG CONSOLE**

   > Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
   >   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/.
   >   For help, type "help".
   >   Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
   >   Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
   >   Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
   >   Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:6
   >   6     std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
   >   [Inferior 1 (process 21973) exited normally]
   >   The program '/home/naos/Desktop/c++/examples/a.out' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
4. **TERMINAL**

   > `naos@spaceship:~/Desktop/c++/examples$` ruta actual del proyecto

---

> ¿Por qué la pestaña de `OUTPUT` se muestra siempre vacía y nunca me salta el `Hello World` como se espera?

Answer (score 2):

1. Para compilar el archivo únicamente necesitas el archivo `task.json`, `launch.json` es para debuggar el código.
2. En el archivo `task.json` en la propiedad `"command"` necesitas indicar el nombre del archivo compilado, en tu caso puede ser "g++ -g main.cpp -o main"; si añades eso puedes omitir añadir la propiedad args.
3. En el archivo `launch.json` en la propiedad `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out"` debes de indicar el nombre del archivo compilado. En tu caso debería de ser `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/main"`.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de como debe de lucir el archivo launch.json.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en caso tienes dudas tengo una guía que actualizo constantemente con los nuevos cambios introducidos en el proceso. https://medium.com/pairzero/c-cpp-en-visual-studio-code-63e49a14c928

Un cambio importante es que ya no necesitas editar las propiedades del archivo `c_cpp_properties.json` ya que la extensión de C/C++ añade el path automáticamente.

Answer (score 1):

También podrías instalar [MinGW](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/) y instalar la extensión Code Runner, y una ves instalado podrás ejecutar el código C++ solamente presionando CTRL+ALT+N.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -3):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503515/how-to-use-visual-studio-c-compiler

Usa Visual Studio 2013, nose si afecte mucha dependiendo de tu versión pero en realidad no creo que pase algo diferente.

Igualmente aquí tienes un video sobre como compilar C en Visual Studio 2015 (en inglés)--->https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuR-54fQrA0:

Nota: jamás he usado Visual Studio.